# 0002 string value getting truncated to 2 while converting to DataTable using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

```
private DataTable ExcelToDataTable(IFormFile file)
    {
        using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = (data) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = true,
                    }
                });

                DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
                DataTable resultTable = table["Employee Information"];

                return resultTable;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hi All,
There  is a column named uniquenumber in excel which contains the value 0002, when the data is converted to DataSet, the column value is changed to 2.

Can anyone help me fixing it ?

Comment: Is the cell formatted as 'Text'?

Comment: There's no truncation if the field's/column's type is numeric. 0002 is equal to 2 and 00000002. If you want the number to be displayed in a specific way, format it during display, eg with a format string or style

Comment: @Hmax : format of the cell is General.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The problem is I have to store the value in DB. 
And the datatype of the column in the db is nvarchar so '2' <> '0002' .

Comment: Have you checked the [AsDataSet configuration options](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#asdataset-configuration-options) ? Have you tried setting `UseColumnDataType = true,` ?

Comment: @Amit if you want to treat that as text you have to *read* it as text. Unless you specify in a column's/cell's style that it's text, it's considered a number.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I just changed cell format from general to text and it worked. And actually when it was general, though I was entering 0002 it was considering it as 2. My bad. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the cell is formatted as 'Text' when the cell is formatted as 'General' and begins with a zero the value is considered a number and all leading zeros are scrapped.